# Amfphp 500 internal server error (sessions)

Tags: php, session, flash, amfphp

So to sketch out our situation

We have a html page(domain: hyves.nl) with an iframe

in that iframe we load a php file (domain : atik.nl)

in that php file we start a session
and we embed our swf file (domain : atik.nl )

in our swf file we access a special page "calls.php" (domain: atik.nl)
where we can get some special data. (that's why we needed to start a session in the first php file so that it can share some authorizing data)

but beside that in our swf we want to connect to our amfphp gateway.php file (domain: atik.nl)

but when i try to do that. Charles (web debugging proxy) tells me i have an 500 server internal error.

Is it because amfphp doesn't do well with a session that is already started on the same domain ?

because when i try to run my amfphp browser it works until i go to the dedicated page, my amfphp browser fails also until i restart my web browser.

anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's at fault but it seems you need to synchronize the two sessions from  hyves.nl and atik.nl . I think for debugging purposes you need to pass something to link these together.

You need to look at the traffic being generated. You might look at the HTTP traffic with a tool like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647). It will show you the traffic generated between your various pages and even show you the payloads, though encoded AMFPHP ends up looking like binary noise.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 500 error, it should be showing in your Apache log... I'd look there for some hints, first.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem. Just delete the .htaccess file in the AMFPHP folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem in error 500, meu server listed in file error_log this lines:

> PHP Warning:  include(core/amf/app/Gateway.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **************daybyday/gateway.php on line 112

Problem in folder: core, files inexistent.
I replace all folders and WORKS great!